# SQL for make new colom but only 1 value for all row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want to add new `category` column and fill it with one same value for all row but I can not do query update for some reason.

I am hoping that my table will be like this:

```
---------------------
no | Name | Category |
1  | A    |   1      |
2  | B    |   1      |
3  | C    |   1      |
4  | D    |   1      |
----------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need an update here if your goal be to simply *view* your data this way.  In that case, just select a constant value for the category:

```sql
SELECT no, Name, 1 AS Category
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY no;
```

Comment: If we use a DDL to add a `Category` column and set the default value to 1, does it mean MySQL will first add a new column and then perform an update statement i.e `update yourTable set Category=1;`  ?

Comment: No...AFAIK the default value would only affect inserts occurring _after_ you set the default value.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, Tim. If no implicit UPDATE statement is performed when adding a new column using a default value, then I suppose the DDL is another option for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new column in your query result set without changing the table structure, please try Tim's answer. Otherwise,you might consider adding a new column to the table and defining a default value for it:

```
alter table yourTable add column Category int default 1;
```